# build a set from 3 lists - Python

Tags: python, list, set

I've got below chunk and I need to define 'Score' as the intersection / union for each set of words in any given two lists. I understand & and | could only be used in sets. From [studytonight](https://www.studytonight.com/python-howtos/how-to-add-a-list-to-a-set-in-python) I get that below code shoud work but it's gving me > TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

```
corpus = [
    ["i","did","not","like","the","service"],
    ["the","service","was","ok"],
    ["i","was","ignored","when","i","asked","for","service"]
]
{corpus[0],corpus[1],corpus[2]}
```

Could someone please correct my mistake?

```
# This is my goal - but all in 1 set
set1 = {"i","did","not","like","the","service"}
set2 = {"the","service","was","ok"}
set3 = {"i","was","ignored","when","i","asked","for","service"}
set1&set3
```

```
# Even like this it gives the same error, wwhy can't I do it?
set = {
    ["i","did","not","like","the","service"],
    ["the","service","was","ok"],
    ["i","was,"ignored","when","i","asked","for","service"]


}
```

Comment: you can't add list as a element in sets, you can only add objects that are hashable you can use `hash()` function to check

Comment: "I need to define 'Score' as the intersection / union for each set of words in any given two lists." Which one do you need, though? The intersection or the union?

Comment: Both, to define the number as an intersection of pairs divided by the union of that pair

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use:

```
data = list(sum(corpus, [])) # this will convert 2d into single D list
result = set(data)
```

or

```
results = set(list(sum(corpus, [])))
```

Comment: it's saying TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: You need to pass the list (corpus)

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but what do you mean by this?

Comment: This is a well-known anti-pattern: `data = list(sum(corpus, [])) # this will convert 2d into single D list` it is very inefficient, and should never be used, indeed, `sum` warns explicitly against using this, and this gives the *union* of everything, not the *intersection*

Comment: And I need them to remain separate by each group

Answer (score 0):

You were looking for:

```
corpus = [
    ["i","did","not","like","the","service"],
    ["the","service","was","ok"],
    ["i","was","ignored","when","i","asked","for","service"]
]

intersection = set.intersection(*map(set, corpus))
```

Or, in a more literal sense:

```
intersection = set(corpus[0]) & set(corpus[1]) & set(corpus[2])
```

Comment: it's saying TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: @MelaniaCB because you've used `map` as a variable, probably, and shadowed the built-in `map`.

Comment: Here's a cutsey version of the intersection one: `set(next(it:=iter(corpus))).intersection(*it)`, I would definitely just use `set.intersection(*map(set, corpus))` though before that one.